# tabbed document interface in WPF using only on-board means?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, tabbed-document-interface, tabbed-interface

I've seen two threads here about TDI & C#. Both of them didn't really answer the questions I have ...

Since TDIs are pretty much like a standard nowadays, I can hardly imagine, that I have to buy a special control (like AvalonDock or SandDock). 
This must be possible with built in the tab-control(?) somehow! I don't need special features like dock- and draggable tabitems. Just open every form in a new tab. Thats it.

Like putting every forms content controls into user controls and by request (button, menu click ...) add a new tab and put the corresponding user control on it ... something like this.

How would you do it? This can't be THAT complicated (even for me) or am I missing something?!

thanks a lot!

Comment: well, which should I mark as answer? All 3 probably work - I currently try to figure out what Josh Smith is doing in this article posted by idursun. Its a very elegant solution, but kinda difficult to figure out for me as a beginner. What answers my actual question best is Josh G.'s post, I guess, so I'll mark his... Big thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that hard. It seems hard because there are a lot of different ways to do it.

Try this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="documentArea"/>
```

Handler for AddForm button:

```
private void AddFormClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object form = GetNewForm();

    documentArea.Items.Add(form);
}
```

That's it. You have to implement `GetNewForm()` in one of two ways. Have it return a user control that displays the form.

OR better yet, have it return your document that you want to display. Use a `DataTemplate` to select the controls to use for displaying this document. This method is going to be more complex to set up.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe Josh Smith's [article on MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) can give you an idea how to design such user interface. Example being built there is kinda tabbed document interface so you can use it as a starting block.

Comment: Be warned... Josh Smith's article is a great reference, but it is not simple to understand. You'll need a good handle on WPF's databinding to piece this together.

Comment: Thanks, considering @mad9's previous questions I think he is getting closer to implementing MVVM  :)

Comment: I'm all for that. MVVM is a great tool for WPF!

Comment: Thank you very much, I already have the german version of the article ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/dd419663.aspx ) printed, right before me =)